# Missing "Flow Email Alert" element" in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert

I don't see the "Flow Email Alert" element as a choice when creating a Flow.  Do I need to do something to make it available?

Comment: Do you mean email alert action which comes inside action

Comment: if you want to add email alert you created you can search in actions by name

Comment: @KushalChauhan - please add your response as an answer

Answer (score 1):

To find the email alert action, you have to select Actions under interactions. Drop the Actions Elements onto the flow. Then in the filter by selection, you want to choose "Type" instead of "Category". You will then see "Email Alert". :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an email alert that already exists,you can search it in actions by its name Or you can create your own Send email action within the flow.

Comment: Thanks.  I got it by doing what you mentioned.  I still have the problem I posted in my other question as to how to dynamically specify who I want the email to go to.